# Swift get struct properties from type reference

Tags: swift, generics, struct, properties

I'm trying to loop over the struct properties but I only have reference for struct type not fully initialized struct. if I were to have an initialized struct I can use the mirror methods but I only have a type reference from generics.

---

Here in my code I'm trying to generate other code for some reason  I'll create function arguments from struct properties.

```
class LoginRequiredRule<T: Request>: Rule {

    var validator: (T) -> Void
    init(validator: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        self.validator = validator
    }
    let a = T.Type.self
    func generateTree(_ depth: Int, path: String) -> String {
        var o = "";
        // i need to loop over the properities of T here but i only have access to T.self
        return o;
    }
}
```

I tried using the objc foundation functions to access struct but I don't know objc . 
Is this even possible in swift runtime?

I know I can implement a protocol that contains static reference to properties but there has to be a swifty way